# Al terminar un superstep y hacer flush, un container es asesinado (killed) por que usa mucha memoria, a pesar de que le queda bastante - Giraph

Tags: java

Estoy ejecutando una aplicacion **Giraph** en **EMR**. Para esto, estoy usando un cluster de 1 master y 10 esclavos (CORE), todos son m3.2xlarge.

La aplicacion consiste en un BFS que recorre la version en español de wikipedia (obviamente, adapte la informacion de esta pagina para que pueda ser cargada correctaemente en Giraph)

Ejecuté la aplicación de la siguiente manera:

```
/home/hadoop/bin/yarn jar /home/hadoop/giraph/giraph.jar ar.edu.info.unlp.tesina.lectura.grafo.algoritmos.masivos.BusquedaDeCaminosNavegacionalesWikiquotesMasivo /tmp/vertices.txt 4 -@- 1 ar.edu.info.unlp.tesina.lectura.grafo.BusquedaDeCaminosNavegacionalesWikiquote -vif ar.edu.info.unlp.tesina.vertice.estructuras.IdTextWithComplexValueInputFormat -vip /user/hduser/input/grafo-wikipedia.txt -vof ar.edu.info.unlp.tesina.vertice.estructuras.IdTextWithComplexValueOutputFormat -op /user/hduser/output/caminosNavegacionales -w 10 -yh 11500 -ca giraph.metrics.enable=true,giraph.useOutOfCoreMessages=true,giraph.isStaticGraph=true,giraph.numInputThreads=4,giraph.numOutputThreads=4
```

Puedo ejecutar correctamente esta aplicación con 3 supersteps, pero si quiero ejecutarla con 4, un container es asesinado (por que su uso de RAM se pasa del limite) y el resto de los workers fallan en consecuencia.

Buscando en los logs del Application Manager de Giraph, dice lo siguiente:

```
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : ip-172-31-0-147.sa-east-1.compute.internal:9103
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: START_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000005
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : ip-172-31-0-145.sa-east-1.compute.internal:9103
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000009
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000011
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000004
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000010
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000006
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000007
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000008
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000005
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000002
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000012
16/08/15 03:44:32 INFO impl.NMClientAsyncImpl: Processing Event EventType: QUERY_CONTAINER for Container container_1471231949464_0001_01_000003
16/08/15 03:46:53 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: Got response from RM for container ask, completedCnt=1
16/08/15 03:46:53 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: Got container status for containerID=container_1471231949464_0001_01_000008, state=COMPLETE, exitStatus=143, diagnostics=Container [pid=4455,containerID=container_1471231949464_0001_01_000008] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 11.4 GB of 11.3 GB physical memory used; 12.6 GB of 56.3 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1471231949464_0001_01_000008 :
        |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
        |- 4459 4455 4455 4455 (java) 13568 5567 13419675648 2982187 java -Xmx11500M -Xms11500M -cp .:${CLASSPATH}:./*:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:./*:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:./*:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:./*:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/* org.apache.giraph.yarn.GiraphYarnTask 1471231949464 1 8 1 
        |- 4455 2706 4455 4455 (bash) 0 0 115875840 807 /bin/bash -c java -Xmx11500M -Xms11500M -cp .:${CLASSPATH}:./*:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*:$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:./*:/home/hadoop/conf:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/home/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/auxlib/* org.apache.giraph.yarn.GiraphYarnTask 1471231949464 1 8 1 1>/mnt/var/log/hadoop/userlogs/application_1471231949464_0001/container_1471231949464_0001_01_000008/task-8-stdout.log 2>/mnt/var/log/hadoop/userlogs/application_1471231949464_0001/container_1471231949464_0001_01_000008/task-8-stderr.log  

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

16/08/15 03:46:53 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: After completion of one conatiner. current status is: completedCount :1 containersToLaunch :11 successfulCount :0 failedCount :1
16/08/15 03:46:55 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: Got response from RM for container ask, completedCnt=7
16/08/15 03:46:55 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: Got container status for containerID=container_1471231949464_0001_01_000002, state=COMPLETE, exitStatus=1, diagnostics=Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/08/15 03:46:55 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: Got container status for containerID=container_1471231949464_0001_01_000012, state=COMPLETE, exitStatus=1, diagnostics=Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/08/15 03:46:55 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: Got container status for containerID=container_1471231949464_0001_01_000006, state=COMPLETE, exitStatus=1, diagnostics=Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:200)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1

16/08/15 03:46:55 INFO yarn.GiraphApplicationMaster: Got container status for containerID=container_1471231949464_0001_01_000007, state=COMPLETE, exitStatus=1, diagnostics=Exception from container-launch: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: 
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:501)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:655)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:200)
```

Por lo tanto, parecería haber un problema de memoria en el container 8, pero aca se puede ver que en realidad no es tan asi. Las ultimas lineas de log de ese container son las siguientes:

```
16/08/15 03:46:52 INFO graph.ComputeCallable: call: Computation took 23.90834 secs for 10 partitions on superstep 3.  Flushing started
16/08/15 03:46:52 INFO worker.BspServiceWorker: finishSuperstep: Waiting on all requests, superstep 3 Memory (free/total/max) = 4516.47M / 10619.50M / 10619.50M
16/08/15 03:46:52 INFO netty.NettyClient: logInfoAboutOpenRequests: Waiting interval of 15000 msecs, 1307 open requests, waiting for it to be <= 0, MBytes/sec received = 0.0029, MBytesReceived = 0.0678, ave received req MBytes = 0, secs waited = 23.332
MBytes/sec sent = 143.2912, MBytesSent = 3343.4141, ave sent req MBytes = 0.4999, secs waited = 23.332
16/08/15 03:46:52 INFO netty.NettyClient: logInfoAboutOpenRequests: 548 requests for taskId=10, 504 requests for taskId=0, 251 requests for taskId=5, 1 requests for taskId=4, 1 requests for taskId=7, 1 requests for taskId=8,
```

Entonces, si entiendo todo correctamente, el container tenia 4516.47M disponibles antes de hcer flush, y en el moomento que lo hace, consume toda la memoria que quedaba disponible y aun un poco mas, por ende se pasa del maximo, y es asesinado por el application master de Giraph.

No entiendo por que necesita tanta memoria para hacer flush (aunque no entiendo al 100% que es lo que hace el flush)... Y tampoco entiendo como o de que forma corregir este problema.